# Understanding Vue routing

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to understand vue-router. But so far I was not able to get what I need.  In simple terms, when I go to `example.com`, it should show the `Home` component and if I go to `example.com/:id`, I want `SavedComparator` component to be loaded. My `router.js` is as below:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'
import SavedComparator from './views/SavedComparator.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Home,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/:id',
          component: SavedComparator
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

In my `App.vue`, I have below code segment:

```
<v-content>
   <h2>params: {{ $route.params.id }}</h2>
   <router-view />
</v-content>
```

But when I go to `example.com/h8s7f`, it always shows `Home` component. In addition, `$route.params.id` in `App.vue` doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are expecting the router to behave as if it had history mode activated

Either turn history mode on:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
```

Or access the url as example.com/#/h8s7f (with the hash before the route)

Here is an example: you can access the route by adding / + an id
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-routing-example-33p1n?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to start your route with '/' in your nested routes because routes starting from '/' will be considered parent route try this in your children

```
 {
      path: 'comparator/:id', 
      component: SavedComparator
 }
```

and then example.com/comparator/id will route you to correct component

Comment: Thanks @moshin-amjad But I want the path like: `/:id` not `comparator/:id`